# Making subarray from function on multiple arrays

Tags: python-2.7

In one folder I have 13 txt files which have 3 columns of data t, x, y. I use for path in glob to set multiple arrays with the data values. My question is if I want to create a separate array from each of the main arrays (t, x, y)

```
for path in glob("F:\Thermal Motion\*.txt"):
t, x, y = np.loadtxt(path, unpack=True)
for i in range(len(x)):
    D = ((x[i] - x[0])**2 + (y[i] - y[0])**2)**0.5
```

So when I print D, I don't get an array I get a list. I want to sort D into arrays according to the original 13 files. So the data from the first file going through D is one array, and so on...

Comment: What do you mean not list but arrays? There are no arrays in python

Comment: @Stormvirux `numpy` has arrays, which the asker appears to be using.

Comment: @HenryKeiter Ohh I didnt notice that

Comment: Also @Kimi it looks like you need to fix your indentation in at least one spot... as written this doesn't even run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`D` looks like a `float` to me, not an array *or* list. If I understand your need correctly, you need a list of "`D`-values" for each file that you're reading in. Let's say you want those list of values associated with the name of the file that produced them for simplicity; obviously you can reorder them however you want later. Use a list comprehension to store the values, and a dict to map file names to lists of `D` values. Something like this:

```
D_values = {}
for path in glob("F:\Thermal Motion\*.txt"):
    t, x, y = np.loadtxt(path, unpack=True)

    # Add a list of computed D values to the D_values dictionary.
    D_list = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        D = ((x[i] - x[0])**2 + (y[i] - y[0])**2)**0.5
        D_list.append(D)
    D_values[path] = D_list
```

The example above is extra verbose for clarity. If I were writing this code for real, I'd use a list comprehension rather than the explicit inner loop:

```
D_values = {}
for path in glob("F:\Thermal Motion\*.txt"):
    t, x, y = np.loadtxt(path, unpack=True)

    D_values[path] = [((x[i] - x[0])**2 + (y[i] - y[0])**2)**0.5 
                      for i in range(len(x))]
```